# Which QT/KDE theme is this?

Tags: debian, kde, qt

I am on mate and run only couple of programs from QT/KDE. One of them is qbittorrent

[image: latest qbittorrent as in debian as of date]

I saw that the theme changed and became better but clueless which theme it is and due to which package upgrade it happened. Does anybody have any idea ?

By theme I mean the colors which you can, blue or whatever the color is, the color by which you can see all the progress of the torrents as well as the checkbox which is filled in next to STATUS as well as again the checkbox next to LABELS as well as the highlighted ALL (300) . I haven't shared either the torrents nor the Labels as they aren't pertinent to this discussion.

Look forward to knowing from you. .

Comment: That looks like the standard Breeze theme to me.

Answer (score 0):

Breeze for the widget style, Plastik for the window decoration.